# How to add a third-party component in my web application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui, custom-component

What I have figured out is that first I have to mention the link of the `css` files in the header, then I have to mention the link of the `js` files before the  tag. But I failed to use a component from `semantic-ui.com` using this approach. I want something like this. [image]

It is called "Multiple Search Selection" in `semantic-ui.com`. What I did is that:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="">
  <option value="">State</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>

</select>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting no error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the console you can see the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at semantic.min.js:11
```

You need to also add [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Edit:
Also, you need to initialize it with .dropdown() command like this

```
$('select').dropdown();
```

working example here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxgv7b2q/1/)

Comment: Compressed, production jQuery?

Comment: Now I added jQuery link. Even now I can't use the component. @Janar

Comment: Ah, you also need to initialize it!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in a tutorial.
The jQuery link should be included in the `head`, or at least before calling `$('select').dropdown();`